# Linear independence of matrix columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix}A_1&\cdots &A_n\end{bmatrix}$

The matrix equation $Ax=0$ be written as

$x_1A_1+x_2A_2+\cdots+x_nA_n =0$

Can anyone explain why the following statement is true

> Each linear dependence relation among the columns of $A$ corresponds to a nontrivial solution of $Ax=0$.

and provide some examples?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: But when you write, "The matrix equation $Ax=0$ can be written as $x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n=0$," you are saying precisely that solutions of $Ax=0$ correspond to linear dependence relations among the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Look at a concrete example:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and write out
$$
Ax = 0,  
$$
i.e.,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=  \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get
\begin{align}
2x_1 + 1x_2 &= 0\\
6x_1 + 3x_2  &= 0
\end{align}
The solutions to this are things of the form 
\begin{align}
x_1 = 2a \\
x_2 = a
\end{align}
although this doesn't really matter much for the question you've asked. Still, it's nice to see.

Compare this with writing out a linear dependence relation between the columns of $A$. Those columns are 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
6
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and they are linearly dependent *exactly* if there are numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ with the property that 
$$
x_1 \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
6
\end{bmatrix} + x_2  
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
If you write that out as a pair of individual equations, they become
\begin{align}
2x_1 + 1x_2 &= 0\\
6x_1 + 3x_2  &= 0
\end{align}
which is *exactly the same set of equations we had before*. Summary: a solution 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
to the equation $Ax = 0$ has as its entries a pair of coefficients that can be used to form a linear combination of $A$'s columns which ends up equalling the zero-vector. If these coefficients are nonzero, then $A$'s columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: Hi professor, I'm not sure I'm understand, could you give example of linear independent to show the difference?

Comment: Please help :(:(